# Most appreciate way to transfer static values?

Tags: java, variables, static

What's most appreciated way to transfer static values from main application?

1. Should I create a different settings file which holds all static values?
2. I noticed that I can use the static values i.e with following:

> `Application application = new Application();`

3. I noticed that I can also use return in main class which contains statics i.e:

> ```
> public getWeb() {
>     return MY_STATIC;
> }
> ```

4. Or I can simply pass them via calling void and using constructor of called void, but I were thinking it is a good way if I have i.e 30 statics I need so I need to create a pretty long constructor in order to pass them from main to called function.

Any great tips? I'm basically looking for a tips how professionals does that so code doesn't look ugly and is pretty easy to read and pretty easy to use as object-oriented.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. I also think that this post includes several different questions. It might be better to break it into short focused, preferably including example, question. This for example `Application application = new Application();` has got nothing to do with "transferring static values". It creates an `Application` object.

Comment: @c0der from this object I'm able to read the static value in another class. That's why I wrote above: "I were afraid that the static void main will be executed. Does it?" PS. I think it shouldn't execute main void on calling only a object itself. Maybe using this method I'll be able to use static values in another class, but wondering about the different choices which is most appreciate way.

Comment: If you're asking whether creating a new `Application` automatically causes `main` to be executed: no.

Comment: @ajb yes, it was one of the off-questions related to statics. I'm looking for most appreciate/professional way to use main class static variables/values in another classes. When I use it this way it says warning (not error) that the static value should be accessed as static way or something similar.

Comment: " it was one of the off-questions" that is why I suggest to break the post down to concise questions,

Comment: @c0der Wait a couple of minutes so I reformat my question so your don't need to hurt your mind about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key thing to know: **static** is an abnormality in good OO design. Of course, when one begins with Java, using static seems natural and straight forward. *main* is static, so things look easier when anything else is static is, too.

But, as said: *static* should be the exception; not the "normal" thing in your code. So instead of spending time on "how do create a good design around static"; you should step back and look into "how do I create good designs that **avoid** static"!

A good starting point would be to learn about the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.

Long story short: design your classes so that you can instantiate, so that your code is dealing with **objects** that have a meaningful purpose!